# Make a div move in one direction each time I click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make code for a gallery that shows thumbnails on click:

I make one div named "track" and inside are the thumbnails.

Now with my current code, when I press the button it movea just in left for -100px
when I click again nothing happens. I want this to be continuous.
10 is margin position

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var a = 10;
    var b = 10;
    var c = function () {
        if (a >= b) {
            a = b - 100;
            return (a);
        }
    };
    $('#track').css({
        'margin': '10px ' + c() + 'px',
        'transition-duration': '1s'
    });
});
```

So, after that code c returns -90px
and idk if he save in css to new value from margin: 10px 10px; to margin; 10px -90px;

if somebody has any idea how to make that after each clik move for -100px?

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82HKq/)

Comment: When you click again, what needs to happen? If you're just moving *another* 100px left, you need to get the current position and subtract another 100px off it, each time the button is clicked

Comment: I don't get it, `10 >= 10` will always be true, so why do you need a function for that? Are you trying to just subtract 100px from the margin on each click ?

Comment: andeneo: yeah, every time i click button to make -100px more

helion3: exactly that i need, but i dont know how to make it.

Comment: @user3272113 can you put the rest of the code in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82HKq/) I provided?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zKB98/ ( If you change the `+` to `-`, you can animate it to the left. I just thought it was easier to demonstrate like this.  )

Comment: @Jonathan its updated to full gallery im trying to build, and you will see there red button witch shuld do his job

Comment: @Joonas this script is exactly what i need, but wont work in my site

Comment: I can only guess that it might be that you have older jquery version. Check your console to see what it has to say.

Comment: jQuery is v1.9.1
is good?

Comment: Should work with anything above v.1.7. || There is a chance that some of your other code is conflicting with it somehow, given that I know that the code I wrote works. Difficult to guess blindly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/82HKq/1/
this is fidle of what im building
when you click yellow field it will open down part where is problem
that red field is button witch shuld continue move div with thumbnails

Comment: Well the problem is probably the fact that I can't find my code in your jsfiddle at all. All you need to do is replace the `#apDivvv2` click event in your code with the one I wrote and replace the selectors with the ones in your click event.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fqwE2/
here solution with your code
thanx for trying help :D

Comment: You already have a document ready in there. The `$(function() { ... });` in my code is a shorthand for document ready. Just remove it around my code and it works. || By the way, you might want to click that TidyUp button in jsfiddle. It'll clean up the code for you. Makes it easier to read/understand.

Comment: thanx sooooo much!
Everything works now good!
now i will play litle bit with code, to put max margin to not move over that margine, and i hope then will all be right. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vars `a` and `b` will be set with the value `10`.
Since `b` is never reset again anywhere in you code, your function will always return `b - 100` that is in fact `10 - 100`. So it will only move at this position once.

```
    var a = 10;
    var b = 10;
    var c = function () {
        if (a >= b) {
            a = b - 100;
            return (a);
        }
```

What you want, if i understand correctly, is to change the value every time you hit the button. In the code below, i get `var a = 10;` outside of the click definition. I remove the var `b` and i decrement your `a` at every click. You should probably add a condition to stop this effect at a certain point.

```
var a = 10;
$("#apDivvv2").click(function() {   
var c = function () {
    a-=100;
    return a;
};

$('#track').css({'margin':'10px ' + c() + 'px', 'transition-duration':'1s'});
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/82HKq/3/) is your updated jsfiddle

Comment: im working to add that condition to stop for example after -800px.
but nothing want work..
there shuld be for loop i gues.
but anyway thanx for help :D

Comment: If you want to use a fixed value, you can add a condition like `if ( a > -400 ) { a-=100; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works once because of this:

The first time it runs a = b. After the moving -100px, `a = -90px` and `b = 10`, so `a<b`. This is why clicking on it again doesn't work because it doesn't satisfy the condition inside if.

You need to put your actions inside a the click function, not outside to render it.

Comment: i was change in many ways code, to try difirent, but stild dont works.

Comment: if you post your code in jsfiddle, I can try to take a look and help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/82HKq/2/

here,  this is fidle of what im building when you click yellow field it will open down part where is problem that red field is button witch shuld continue move div with thumbnails